# django not add auto increment primary key id when save an article

Tags: django, django-templates

I hava an article app installed in django admin site,when i finish editing one article,I click the save button,but an error page:

[image]

**article/models.py**

```
# blog category models
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='category name')
    description = models.TextField(default='',help_text='category description')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    categories = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article_category'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#blog article models
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,'on'),
        (1,'off')
    )
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,help_text='foreigner key reference Category')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='article title')
    content = models.TextField(help_text='article content')
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0,help_text='like numbers')
    secretcode = models.CharField(max_length=512,help_text='who has the code can scan')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS,help_text='status of the article')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,help_text='time that first created')
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,help_text='time when modified')

    articles = models.Manager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'
```

**article/widgets.py**

```
from pagedown.widgets import AdminPagedownWidget
from django import forms
from .models import Article

class ArticleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=AdminPagedownWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title','category', 'content', 'secretcode', 'status')
```

**article/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .widgets import ArticleModelForm
from .models import Article,ArticleImage,Category

class  MMBArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ArticleModelForm

admin.site.register(Article,MMBArticleAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(ArticleImage)
```

the page in the admin site looks like：

[image]

and then I click save ,the error page show up like above!why did this happen?and how to fix it?

Comment: look at [Django Girls](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/README.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've overridden the default automatic field with a manual non-autoincrementing ID. Don't do that. Remove your `id` fields altogether.

Comment: oh,i see,what if i manually add the primary key?should i pass `auto_created=True` as parameter to the declaration of id?

Comment: No, that's not what that parameter does. You would need to use AutoField instead of IntegerField. But as I say, you shouldn't be defining that field at all.